# Access Drupal's Voting API from theme

Tags: drupal

I'm a king of a noob in drupal.
I'm trying to use Voting API and Advanced Pool module, now I'm customizing node-advpoll_binary.tpl.php template, and i can access only the total votes.
I'd like to know how get the poll results for each answer in order to calculate percentage results.
Does anyone have the solution??

Answer (score 0):

You don't typically want to do calculations in the theme layer. You may be able to output the numbers you're looking for using the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: Yes I agree. My real issue is finding a Drupal Module with write-in answer available. I have tried Advanced Poll Module but it's in dev for Drupal 6 and it has some bugs ( if you choose the write-in answer, the result is duplicated ).

Comment: I resolved it. Using Voting API and Advanced Pool module to access votes i used Voting API function votingapi_select_results().